# Arch Linux extremelly slow and laggy

Tags: linux, performance, arch-linux

I was looking for an distribution that has Android Studio built in and came across 'BBQLinux'. The Android Studio works, but it's extremelly slow, to the point where it's unusable.

I downloaded the Oracle JDK and updated Android Studio's configuration to use the new JDK, instead of openSDK. That made a small difference in speed, but still unusable.

I noticed that it's not just Android Studio, but everything is lagging. If I move my mouse over an icon/menu or any control, the mouseover change takes about 500ms-1s to complete.

I'm probably wrong, but it looks like the system is missing a video driver or something, I can't think of anything else, because I have enough RAM 500MB free when I run the Android Studio. The CPU usage is around 25% and I have 5 GB of disk free.

Anther problem could be that I'm running it from USB flash drive, but then again I was running Kubuntu 14.04 from USB and it was running very smooth.

The terminal (ctrl+alt+f1) works super fast, the terminal in X11 works a bit laggy.

I'm confused where to even start diagnosing the problem. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See 2 issues here:

1) having run a Live instance for any length of time on /from a USB WILL severely tank the life and speed of the USB.

2) for android studio WAY MORE then 500Mb of free ram is gonna be needed, if disk space is  available (running as a live /semi live instance from usb)   create a swap file on the system's native internal hdd/ssd ...  further more,  5g of disk space for nearly ANY modern distro with something as heavy as android studio is a total non-starter you will need 5g + for / and the essential stuff and arguably twice that for /home (for android studio projects ---assumes this is a solely development environment)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't make myself clear, I got 5GB of storage left after I have installed and setup everything. I can build/run the android apps, it's just extremelly slow. My USB is 16 GB and my RAM is 2GB in total.

Comment: I personally  would NOT do this on less than a 32 gb usb if its available and financially feasible...  2gb of ram for android studio is at the absolute bottom of  working limit and with only 5g  remaining it has no "room to breath" hence part of the reason for the performance hit the heavy use of the usb earlier by another live instance has not helped you much either.

Comment: Besides Android Studio, do you have any suggestions on why the interface (Gnome) itself is slow, when nothing is running? could it be due to missing/bad video drivers? Kubuntu was running very smooth